# How to stopPropagation when there are multiple event delegations

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegation

I have a table row in which there is an  element with an event handler delegated to document element, and the row itself also has another handler delegated to the tbody element. Codes like below:

```js
// first part is defined in an initiating script file, so no jQuery used.
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target;

    if (el && el.classList && el.classList.contains('gotocontact')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('going to contact...')
    }
})
// second part is defined after the jQuery included...
$('#list').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('click tr...')})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody id="list">
        <tr>
            <td><a class="gotocontact">John Doe</a></td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="gotocontact">Jane Doe</a></td>
            <td>Female</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I put the stopPropagation there but it doesn't work as I expected: when I click the a element, the tr handler should not be triggered.
Anyone can provide some hints?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and non jQuery? Pick one and use it. Your stopping propagation at the top level, this fires after the tr click, so there is nothing to stop. You can't stop lower events firing from higher ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the jQuery listener from triggering, you should call `stopPropagation` in the *capturing* phase rather than in the *bubbling* phase, by passing a third `true` argument to `addEventListener`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target;

    if (el && el.classList && el.classList.contains('gotocontact')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('going to contact...')
    }
}, true)
// ^^^^ add third parameter

$('#list').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('click tr...')})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody id="list">
        <tr>
            <td><a class="gotocontact">John Doe</a></td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="gotocontact">Jane Doe</a></td>
            <td>Female</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add stopPropagation in function that you added on 'tr' element. That should work

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
  if (el && el.classList && el.classList.contains('gotocontact')) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('going to contact...')
 }
})
// second part is defined after the jQuery included...
$('#list').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 alert('click tr...')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the problem here is that inside your `td` there's `a` tag and the natural behaviour of `a` tag is that it takes you to the new page so instead of using `e.stopPropagation()` use `e.preventDefault()`.
Hope, It might help you. And you can also pass true in the third argument where you are setting your event listener.